# Logging not working if I import the module

Tags: python

I have a module which should do some logging:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
def do_something():
    logging.info("I did something")
```

Now if I call the module, let it be module.py, then it will not do the logging:

```
import module
module.do_something()
```

Not even a logfile is created! Where is the bug?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules?

Comment: sure, but maybe I did a mistake in thinking, if you see an issue just tell me!

Comment: Maybe the colon after `module.do_something():` ?

Comment: Without that trailing colon it all works for me...

Comment: @ larsks: You are sure? It did not work for me!

Comment: Does it work if you add the line `do_something()` to `module.py`, and then run `module.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to specify the full path of the log file. Try that. For example:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='C:/workspace/logging_proj/src/example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

or you can have Python do it for you:

```
import os
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'example.log')
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)
```